# Forex MT4 platform - what type of protocol(s)/technology is used to update the charts in real-time?

Tags: c#, rest, websocket, communication, metatrader4

Forex MT4 platform - what type of protocol(s)/technology is used to update the charts in real-time?

- Websocket?
- soap/restful web service?
- other?

The data is updated in real-time,

Answer (score 5):

### Initial note

A lot of indeed **smart** man*years has been burnt on reverse-engineered efforts to tap into **`MT4/Server`** <--> **`MT4/Terminal`** C/S communication.

Some have died by themselves.

Some have failed to survive the next change introduced by just another Build XYZ.

Some have even made their way up to the court suits from MetaQuotes, Inc., for violation or infringements of the rights to protect one´s intellectual property.

So, one shall rather really know, what is going to follow.

### How it works?

Recent **`MT4/Terminal`** Build 670+ uses several regular streaming connections to **`MT4/Server`**

It does not take much time or efforts to employ a port-scanner of whatever brand to map, decode and analyse further internals. Nevertheless, do not rather forget the warning, [**Initial note**] rulez.

There are **no direct ways** to "update" OHLC-candle / Volume objects of the **`MT4/Terminal`** graph

There are **many ways** to add and control additional visual objects into the MT4 graphs, incl. but not limited to, compose a fully-fledged new, layered, augmented GUI, where user-defined <***application-code***> retains the full real-time control of both the **`MVC-GUI`**-elements and the **`TradingExecutionEngine`**.

### Can a current Metatrader proprietary architecture get extended?

**Yes.**

Historically some three principal epochs / approaches were used.

1. 3rd party DLL based communications
2. Windows O/S services based communications
3. MetaQuotes, Inc., "new"-MQL4 ( post Build 600+ ) language extensions for socket communications

User-defined <***application-code***> can safely deploy rather a thread-safe external messaging infrastructure, to better "escape" from a (fragile, namely in post Build 670+ epoch) MT4 internalities and retain a full control over the "own" messaging / streaming layer.

### Examples

**`MT4/Terminal`** with socket/remote **`python`**-based CLI terminal & add-on pseudo-language for both trading and scripted test-case batteries´ automated runs

**`MT4/Terminal`** with socket/remote external integrated RSS-feed service

**`MT4/Terminal`** with socket/remote GPU-hosted numerical solver for AI/ML decision making

**`MT4/Terminal`** with socket/remote cloud-based peer-to-peer community messaging

Comment: I still dont get how its so fast? they need to keep the data updated in real time! and thats hard!

Comment: Be specific. What do you consider fast? There are 1.000 msec, 1.000.000 usec, 1.000.000.000 nsec each second the CPU is working, so good RealTime-system code-design can do a lot. The hard part is the good design, not the time or the data.

Comment: @001 for your rough view about how fast the streaming shall be, you may be interested in figures depicted in >>> http://stackoverflow.com/a/24750485/3666197

Comment: @001 would you mind to [Accept] the Answer provided, sir?

Answer (score 2):

All communications between MT4 server and MT4 terminal is done through TCP sockets and data is transferred in plain text.

Example connection to MT4 server on port 443 using telnet

```
telnet x.x.x.x 443
```

Requesting quotes for EURUSD

```
WQUOTES-EURUSD
```

When you open a chart in MT4 terminal, terminal requests historical chart data from the server and subscribes to new ticks for that symbol, Then every time a new tick arrives for the selected chart, MT4 terminal updates last candle in chart or creates a new one when necessary.

All the above is done through the same protocol.